# Maui MVVM - NotifyPropertyChangedFor not working with complex object and its child property

Tags: c#, mvvm, maui, community-toolkit-mvvm

I'm trying to use `CommunityToolkit.MVVM` in a MAUI 8 project. I'm facing difficulty with notifying using `NotifyPropertyChangedFor`.

The ViewModel has a boolean variable `CanSubmitForm`, which only gets scoped at the beginning when the VM is appearing (before my API call completes) and not after it. I've decorated a complex object with `NotifyPropertyChangedFor`, and the object is getting populated after the API returned values. I'm trying to enable the button after `StudentInfo` and its child objects are populated and Gradconditions (child object) are met:

The complex object looks like:

### Model:

```
public class StudentInfo
{
    public string Id {get; set;}
    public string? StudentName {get; set;}
    public string StudentAddress {get; set;}
    public List<Checks>? Gradconditions {get; set;}
}
```

In my ViewModel I've following properties:

### ViewModel:

```
[ObservableProperty]
[NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(CanSubmitForm))]
private StudentInfo? student;

[ObservableProperty]
[NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(CanSubmitForm))]
private int conditionsMet;
```

I also have a boolean variable to enable/disable the form submission button:

```
public bool CanSubmitForm
{
    get => ConditionsMet == Student.Gradconditions.Count;
}
```

And then I have a method to submit the form:

```
[RelayCommand(CanExecute = nameof(CanSubmitForm))]
private void SubmitForm()
{
    /*Do housekeeping and submit form*/
}
```

On page load method, I'm populating all fields on the complex `StudentInfo` object from an API call, and then if conditions in my `CanSubmitForm` are met, I'm enabling the button for form submission.

```
public async Task OnAppearingAsync(string studentId)
{
    /* populate StudentInfo object and ConditionsMet from API */

}
```

On the page, I've the button like so:

### View:

```
<Button 
    Text = "Submit"
    Command="{Binding SubmitFormCommand}"
/>
```

What am I doing wrong? My suspicion is that I can't perform `NotifyPropertyChangedFor` on child objects and propagate them to the parent object that has the decoration. How can I achieve the desired result of `NotifyPropertyChangedFor` on the count of the child object, which is a list?

Comment: Please show the code where you populate the Student object

Comment: It seems that you're misunderstanding how property change notifications work. They don't get triggered when child properties of an observable property get changed. The `Student` property won't know that you made changes to it's properties, you'll need to make the `StudentInfo` class observable and then subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event of that class. Then you can propagate the change notification further up the chain. The list should also become an `ObservableCollection`, then you can subscribe to its `CollectionChanged` event.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with the code you shared.

First, since you want to enable the Button(`Submit`) based on the value of property `CanSubmitForm`, you need to add `ObservableProperty` and `NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor` for property `CanSubmitForm`

```
    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(SubmitFormCommand))]
    public bool canSubmitForm = false;
```

Second, if we add some items to property `public List<Checks>? Gradconditions {get; set;}`, we cannot notify property `Student` in the view model simply with the following code,even if you define it as `public ObservableCollection<string>? radconditions = new ObservableCollection<string>();`:

```
[ObservableProperty]
[NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(CanSubmitForm))]
private StudentInfo? student;
```

Based on your code ,I created a demo and tried to implement basic functions.

I added another `Button` to add some fake data to the `Radconditions` to simulate this scenario.

You can refer to the following code:

```
public partial class MyViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(CanSubmitForm))]
    private StudentInfo? student = new StudentInfo();

    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(CanSubmitForm))]
    private int conditionsMet = 2;


    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(SubmitFormCommand))]
    public bool canSubmitForm = false;

    //public bool CanSubmitForm
    //{
    //    get => ConditionsMet == Student.Gradconditions.Count;
    //}


    [RelayCommand(CanExecute = nameof(CanSubmitForm))]
    private void SubmitForm()
    {
        /*Do housekeeping and submit form*/

    }
    [RelayCommand]
    private void AddItems() {

        Student.Gradconditions.Add("1");
        Student.Gradconditions.Add("2");

        if (Student.Gradconditions.Count == ConditionsMet) {

            CanSubmitForm = true;

        }else
        {
            CanSubmitForm = false;
        }

    }
}
```

**StudentInfo.cs**

```
public partial class StudentInfo : ObservableObject
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string? StudentName { get; set; }
    public string StudentAddress { get; set; }

    [ObservableProperty]       
    public ObservableCollection<string>? gradconditions = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    //public List<string>? Gradconditions { get; set; } =new List<string>();
}
```

**Usage example:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MauiApp323.ViewModels"
             x:Class="MauiApp323.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:MyViewModel></vm:MyViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <VerticalStackLayout
            Padding="30,0"
            Spacing="25">

            <Button  Text = "Submit" Command="{Binding SubmitFormCommand}"/>

            <Button Text="add data to list" Command="{Binding AddItemsCommand}"/>

    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```